# Why do the first digits of disassembled instructions in gdb not match the value in rip? Can anyone provide background?

Tags: gdb, memory-address

First time disassembling a program in a few months using GDB and on a new linux VM.  Last time, when I disassembled a program, set a breakpoint, and ran, the value returned by "i r rip" would EXACTLY match the address of one of the program instructions.

This time, the value returned by "i r rip" == 0x5...54699 <main+15" while the assembly address shown for <+15> == "0x0...0699".

Is GDB now using relative addressing and zeroing the more significant (irrelevant?) address bits similar to what Wireshark does for sequence numbers?

This is my screen dump:
[Disassembled code and rip query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Gk5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at p[osition-independent executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables) (PIE).

This executable is linked to load at address `0`, and is relocated to `0x54...` address on execution.

If you `disas main` *before* first running the binary, GDB will show the original linked-at addresses. If you do the same command *after* first run, GDB will show relocated (actual) addresses.

You can also link non-PIE binary with `gcc t.c -no-pie`. That binary will exhibit the behavior you expect: the output of `disas main` will not change between before and after first run, and the disassembly will match the actual value of `rip` at runtime.

Comment: Great concise explanation.  Thank you!!